# google rich snippet how to display job list?

Tags: google-rich-snippets

How can i let "google rich snippet" display this format such as the following?

rich snippet display the "Job Title", "Company", "Location", "Posted"

---

[glassdoor jobs - Computerworld](http://itjobs.computerworld.com/a/all-jobs/list/q-glassdoor)

25+ items - 5158+ glassdoor jobs available on Computerworld.

Job Title  Company  Location    Posted.

Senior Software Engineer ...    Riverbed Technology Sunnyvale, CA   Aug 09.

Senior Java Software Engineer   Glassdoor.com   Manhattan, NY   Aug 17.

---

is it use microdata, mircoformat or RDFa?

or need to write the specific HTML structure?

i know the JobPosting of microdata, but i think this format is more better to me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's "bulleted snippets".
※ Use a consistent structure, whatever it is.
※ Keep extraneous code to a minimum.
※ Test removing your META description or setting it to “”.
http://moz.com/blog/how-do-i-get-googles-bulleted-snippets
http://insidesearch.blogspot.tw/2011/08/new-snippets-for-list-pages.html